# how to send lines/messages to maillog file

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, logs, mail-command

under /var/log , we can see the following maillog files

```
-rw-------   1 root      root      11733421 Aug  5 03:47 maillog-20180805
-rw-------   1 root      root      15566137 Aug 13 03:16 maillog-20180813
-rw-------   1 root      root      11155484 Aug 19 15:37 maillog-20180819
-rw-------   1 root      root      14527085 Aug 27 03:37 maillog-20180827
-rw-------   1 root      root       6970662 Aug 30 17:25 maillog
```

we want to use the log maillog , by send some messages from cronjob

for example

how to send the message "**454 wsp files was deleted**"

to **maillog** file ?

so the line **454 wsp files was deleted** will be in maillog file

my goal is to use the maillog file , instead to create another new logfile under /var/log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the details of your system, I would suggest something along the lines of `logger -p mail.warning 454 esp files was deleted`. Adjust the level as needed to get logged into your files.